# Share of current Excel users who can only open .xls files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

We're creating a tool in Excel, using the .xlsx format, that we would like to provide on a broad basis as an open source document. Ideally, this spreadsheet should be usable to all Excel users, but we're realizing that saving down to .xls removes some key features. I'm trying to find some estimates for the percentage of Excel users who are on older versions of the program and only able to open .xls files.  I believe there are workarounds to open .xlsx files — converters, Google Docs — but for the sake of justifying this decision, I'm mainly curious if anyone has any idea of what the market share is for folks who have older versions of Excel that can only open .xls files.

Comment: One reason your potential *users* might not want to use XLS is because that format could include macros. Although macro-borne viruses are pretty esoteric as a vector now, why take any risk >0? .XLSX by definition cannot include code, so may be deemed "safer".

Comment: It's probably larger than you think. I know many people still using Office 2003 with no plans to upgrade, ever. Some have the Office compatability pack, some don't. I'd go with xls if maximizing compatibility is your concern. All the newer versions still support the older binary versions, so that's the only way to be fully backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The first version of Excel with XLXS files is Office / Excel 2007 on Windows. I think the comparable Mac version was 2008.

In any event, Windows user would need to be using version earlier than Excel 2003 and even so, there is a converter for Excel 2003.

At this point the actual share % will be small, but I do not know numerically. I would guess at well under 10%, maybe even under 5%, the number of users who cannot open an XLSX file.

So while there are always stragglers, versions earlier than Excel 2003 are long out of support.

[First version of Excel with XLXS](https://thesmartmethod.com/excel-versions-explained/#:%7E:text=Excel%202007%20(Windows),-Excel%202007%20was&text=xlsx%20and%20.,greatly%20improved%20in%20this%20version.)

Excel 2007 was only released for Windows computers.

> Excel 2007 was a significant leap forward from earlier versions,
> introducing the new Ribbon interface and changing the file format from
> the familiar .xls to the new .xlsx and .xlsm files.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any direct estimate, yet, but I did find an interesting page from the Library of Congress:

https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000510.shtml

Search for "The corpus of existing spreadsheet documents on the open web has roughly equal numbers of the binary XLS format and the XML-based XLSX format." or some subset of that to locate the following:

1. .xls:  8,450,000 files
2. .xlsx:  7,630.000 files
3. .ods:  154,000 files

Not to misunderstand their data:  it would not mean that many were placed on the internet in a given year so .xlsx would have a smaller current market share in Excel use! It would be files found on the internet and they might be 25 years old. So while the .xls file count is higher than the .xlsx file count, it could be none at all have been added in the last ten years and not be indicative of any noticeable user base at all.

My belief though, based on other little things like:

1. If someone has no need to use .xlsx-required features, why not use .xls to simply make sure of the largest possible audience?
2. Many software programs go straight to creating .xls files rather than .xlsx, requiring an actual choice be made to get a .xls file. Our company uses three programs that do this.
3. Many people simply want to present the info in an easily used format and have no need for newer features so would not care.

If I were deciding what to do it would depend upon the features I desired to use. If only newer functions, not newer functionalities, I'd consider the difficulty of writing both ways and just use an `IFERROR()` to choose between functions. But if I required Tables (there isn't really any reason to of course, but as an example), I couldn't make a choice.

Recommendation? If you need, or strongly desire, certain functionalities (features), then follow the road that has them. If you do not, then take the inclusive path.

Of course, you could always just simply ask your user base what they use. You could even be "clever" in doing so:  Send the query IN an .xlsx file they edit and save. Unless they've downloaded software to deal with minor file uses like that, they'd have to save it as .xls when returning it to you. Count the number of those vs. the .xlsx returns...

Might consider "outside of the file format" replies as needing .xls formatting. So a text reply, no excel file, would be counted as .xls.

I have heard, in conversation, that maybe 2-3% still use Excel 97-2003.

Comment: Since IFERROR is even newer than the XLSX format, I'm not sure how that would help (since that function itself would break in older versions). On the other hand, Tables are just a development of Lists, which date from Excel 2003 IIRC.
Multiple layers of conditional formatting seems to be a common use case where XLSX is needed as 2003 did not support more than 3, and I think they are unsupported in .XLS file format